# How to overcome Run-Time Check Failure #0 issue?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I'm new to coding and I don't know how to fix this problem. 
I get the message: 
"Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention."

This assignment was supposed to help us get the Chinese zodiac animal. 
Here is my code, it's probably not correct:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;



sign getZNum(int day, int month, int year)
{
    int animalnum;
    enum sign { rat = 0, ox, tiger, rabbit, dragon, snake, horse, goat, monkey, rooster, dog, pig };
    sign animal;

    //figuring out if before or after feb so that I can make sure to bump down the year to the previous year 
    bool beforeFeb2;
    beforeFeb2 = false;
    if (!month > 2) {
        if (month != 2 || (month == 2 && day == 1)) {
            beforeFeb2 = true;
        }

    }
    // The first date is Feb 2, 1924.

    //calculating animalnum
    animalnum = ((year + beforeFeb2) - 1924) % 13;

    //assigning the animal based on animalnum
    switch (animalnum)
    {
    case 0:
        animal = rat;
        break;
    case 1:
        animal = ox;
        break;
    case 2:
        animal = tiger;
        break;
    case 3:
        animal = ox;
        break;
    case 4:
        break;
        animal = rabbit;
        break;
    case 5:
        animal = dragon;
        break;
    case 6:
        animal = snake;
        break;
    case 7:
        animal = horse;
        break;
    case 8:
        animal = goat;
        break;
    case 9:
        animal = monkey;
        break;
    case 10:
        animal = rooster;
        break;
    case 11:
        animal = dog;
        break;
    case 12:
        animal = pig;
        break;
    default: // code to be executed if n doesn't match any cases
        animal = rat;
    }
    cout<< animal;
   return animal;
}

//int getZNum(int, int , int ); 
int main() {

    getZNum(28, 10, 2001);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using #include <assert.h> s? Anyway the C++ version is <cassert>

Comment: Amazed that compiles. `sign` doesn't exist until AFTER it's needed by the return type of `getZNum` What happens if you move it outside of the function. Pop it in an anonymous namespace if you don't want it leaking.

Comment: You have a typo/precedence error  at `if (!month > 2)`. The compiler sees that as `(!month) > 2`, which doesn't make much sense. Do you want `if (!(month > 2))`?

Comment: The switch block can be replaced by `sign animal = static_cast< sign >(animalnum);`

Comment: I changed the top to cassrt and put the 'enum sign' and 'sign animal' outside of the function. I also changed to (!(month > 2)). Thanks for the suggestion on not using the switch statement.

Comment: Also, I have a new problem...I'm getting this "The current stack frame was not found in a loaded module. Source cannot be shown for this location." when I try to run the program. Is this related?

Comment: `sign getZNum(int day, int month, int year)` should not compile with `sign` defined inside the function: `enum sign { rat = 0, ox, tiger, rabbit, dragon, snake, horse, goat, monkey, rooster, dog, pig };`. I unsure how you got that to compile. If this compiles it's a bug in the compiler for allowing it to build successfully. And yes it could corrupt the stack frame.

Comment: One caveat on replacing the `switch` with a cast: You still have to test to ensure the value given is within the valid range for the `enum`. I'd add a `sign_last`or similar to the `enum` and then test `if (animalnum >= sign_last) { handle error }`